# v-switch change boolean v-model

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to do everytime `v-switch` is changed, `switchPackage` is changed to either `true` or `false`.  Nothing appears in console, when i test.  Where did i go wrong?

component

```
<v-switch class="package-switch" v-model="switchPackage" @change="switchPackage!=switchPackage" inset>
                </v-switch>
```

script

```
export default class MembershipProducts extends Vue {
  @Prop() readonly products!: Object;
  data() {
    return {
      switchPackage:false
    }
  };

  watch() {
    switchPackage:(newValue:number) => {
      console.log('switch toggled to ' + newValue);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Is this Vuetify? What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the `v-switch` component automatically sets the v-model (`switchPackage`) on click but you instantly reset it back with `@change="switchPackage!=switchPackage"`. Just remove the `@change` event and it should work.

Comment: Yep, thought about the same.